# Can array_map() and methods using array_map() be #[Pure]?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a function that had the `#[Pure]` attribute, but after I changed the function to use `array_map` in it, PhpStorm complains that the "Method might produce side effects". I also see that `array_map` is not marked as `#[Pure]` and I assume this has to do with the fact that you can't make assumptions about the callback. My callback in this case should be pure since it just calls a pure method.

Is there a way to let the IDE know that this `array_map` is pure, or is there a way I should annotate my callback function?

This is the code:

```
/**
 * @param array $msgArr
 * @return int
 */
#[Pure]  <== this one complains
public function getHighestNumericalCodeFromMessageArray(array $msgArr): int
{
    $numericalCodeArr = array_map(fn($msg) => $this->getNumericalCodeFromMessage($msg) % 99, $msgArr);
    return max($numericalCodeArr);
}

/**
 * @param string $msg
 * @return int
 */
#[Pure]
public function getNumericalCodeFromMessage(string $msg): int
{
    $trimmedMsg = trim($msg);
    if (is_numeric($trimmedMsg)) return (int)$trimmedMsg;
    $code = array_search($trimmedMsg, self::AVAILABILITY_MESSAGES, false);
    return $code !== false ? (int)$code : 0;
}
```

EDIT: I had also tried giving the lambda function the `#[Pure]` attribute as also suggested by Kumara, but this did not remove the warning.

Comment: "The Three Musketeers" `array_map`, `array_reduce`, and `array_filter` are not annotated with `#[Pure]`. So no, it is not (currently) possible. You can check the stubs yourself for any function at https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/standard/standard_9.php#L730 (which is what PhpStorm uses for adding the annotations Pure, Immutable, etc. to the help tooltip in the editor).

Comment: @lukas.j yes, this seems to be the answer. A friend of mine also pointed out https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-56096 "The following function won't have any purity: [...] Function that have `callable` param or param pass by ref"

Feel free to write it as an answer so I can accept it as solved :)

Comment: The only option that **I see** right now is to try and suppress that inspection warning for that function (since you know **for sure** that it will not produce any side effects). Add this (PhpStorm specific thing) to your PHPDoc for `getHighestNumericalCodeFromMessageArray()` function  -- `@noinspection PhpPureFunctionMayProduceSideEffectsInspection`

Comment: @LazyOne oh this is actually very nice! So an otherwise pure function that calls to `getHighestNumericalCodeFromMessageArray()` will not get this warning? That's great

Comment: You have the actual code there / can see where that `getHighestNumericalCodeFromMessageArray()` function get used etc. Check how it looks with and without the suppression bit. But it will surely remove the warning in PhpStorm that it shows for `[#Pure]` line.

Answer (score 1):

Try and inform the IDE that the lambda function inside array_map is pure, you can explicitly annotate the lambda function with the **#[Pure]** attribute as well. But not sure whether, PHPStorm will fully support this attribute for lambdas, but you can try the following approach:

```
#[Pure]
public function getHighestNumericalCodeFromMessageArray(array $msgArr): int
{
    $numericalCodeArr = array_map(
        #[Pure] fn($msg) => $this->getNumericalCodeFromMessage($msg) % 99,
        $msgArr
    );
    return max($numericalCodeArr);
}
```

Comment: I have actually tried this but I forgot to mention it, my apologies! This did not remove the warning

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * @param array $msgArr
 * @return int
 */
#[Pure]
public function getHighestNumericalCodeFromMessageArray(array $msgArr): int
{
    // Suppress PhpStorm warning about impurity
    /** @var callable $pureCallback */
    $pureCallback = fn($msg) => $this->getNumericalCodeFromMessage($msg) % 99;
    
    $numericalCodeArr = array_map($pureCallback, $msgArr);
    return max($numericalCodeArr);
}

/**
 * @param string $msg
 * @return int
 */
#[Pure]
public function getNumericalCodeFromMessage(string $msg): int
{
    $trimmedMsg = trim($msg);
    if (is_numeric($trimmedMsg)) return (int)$trimmedMsg;
    $code = array_search($trimmedMsg, self::AVAILABILITY_MESSAGES, false);
    return $code !== false ? (int)$code : 0;
}
```

In this example, we declare a /** @var callable $pureCallback */ annotation comment to inform PhpStorm that the lambda function assigned to $pureCallback is a callable and considered pure. This should suppress the warning in PhpStorm regarding the lambda function's purity.

However, keep in mind that this is a workaround, and it's important to document the code well so that others who work with it understand the intent. PhpStorm's static analysis capabilities are limited compared to languages with stronger type systems, so sometimes you need to provide these hints to help the IDE understand your code better.

Comment: I doubt this will work, considering that @lukas.j and @LazyOne have already pointed out that array_map is never pure and you need @noinspection for it in your PHPdoc. I can't test your solution at the moment but I fail to see why a PHPdoc like ` /** @var callable $pureCallback */ ` would do anything. This sounds like a ChatGPT hallucination to be honest.

Comment: I took the time to offer you a more speculative solution. it is not a gpt hallucination but you are free not to try it

Comment: I will try it when I'm at work again. If it doesn't work and it really was a ChatGPT answer, I'm calling the police.

Comment: I tried it and the magical (incomplete) PHPdoc annotation did not work